# How to set proxy when using axios to send requests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am using a package called 'concurrently' to run my client and server at the same time on localhost. Client runs on port 3000 while server runs on port 5000. I have set proxy in the package.json of server in the following manner:

```
"proxy": "https://localhost:5000"
```

But when I make a request from client in the following manner:

```
    const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      };

    const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);
```

It says: `POST http://localhost:3000/api/users 404 (Not Found)`. I don't understand why but despite setting proxy, axios keeps making request to port 3000 instead of port 5000. What is the issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue, but restart helped in my case :) Kill dev server and `npm start` or whatever you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working correctly. What I did was:

1) change `axios.post('/api/users', body, config);` to `axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users', body, config);`

2) Then in the 'users' express route on the server side, add CORS functionality by installing 'cors' npm package, and then adding the following lines:

```
const router = express.Router();
...
// add these lines
var cors = require('cors');
router.use(cors()); 
...
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
...
});
```

Comment: I had things working by putting proxy:localhost:5000 in the package.json then axios.post('/api/users',body,config) in the router but things stopped working when I set up debugging

Comment: Hard coding this is not a good Idea. Its much better to have a config var. If you change something youll be hard coding all request for local prod etc. def not the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to say that the solution of adding cors is not a solution. You need to include the proxy `"proxy" : "https://localhost:5000"` in the package.json, you may need to restart or something or other-- but if you choose to use cors instead, you are allowing anyone to access your API. That means your database is wide open for people to poke around with. Passwords, emails, users, etc. It's all compromised.

Comment: Hi - I want to confirm, you meant restart the machine, or just the server?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understood your question, what you need is to refer Axios developer documents. for time being.
[check this](https://janmolak.com/node-js-axios-behind-corporate-proxies-8b17a6f31f9d)

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import * as tunnel from 'tunnel';
   const agent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
   proxy: {
     host: 'proxy.mycorp.com',
     port: 8000,
    },
   });
const axiosClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
baseURL: 'https://some.api.com',
httpsAgent: agent,
});
```

Comment: Nope this is not it. This config is when you are behind a corporate proxy or something, and this is just redirecting local xhr request to backend server which is hosted at different port.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't check well, it appeared that the call was actually forwarded to the api server at the proxy address.
Check that the server is running and whether it is receiving your calls or not.

Answer (score 0):

when I send request to a server with proxy my code works successful. I hope this answer useful to you or another peoples.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function sendRequestWithProxy() {
    let proxyServer = {
        "host" : "YOUR_PROXY_HOST",
        "port" : "YOUR_PROXY_PORT",
        "username" : "YOUR_PROXY_USERNAME",
        "password" : "YOUR_PROXY_PASSWORD"
    };
    var ProductUrl = "http://YOUR_REQUEST_URL";
    await axios.get(ProductUrl, {
        proxy: {
            host: proxyServer.host,
            port: proxyServer.port,
            auth: {username: proxyServer.username, password: proxyServer.password}
        },
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36',            }
    }).then((response) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    let productInfo = $("#HTML_ID_ATTRIBUTE").text();
        ///YOUR CODE
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            //ERROR AREA
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).