# Trouble posting to MongoDB with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I have my express server running on port 5000 and my react application running on port 3000. When I try submitting data to MongoDB, I keep getting the following errors:

Error message when submitting:

[image: Error message when submitting]

I think I am doing something wrong with my sign up form. First I will show the **state variables** I am using in **SignUp.jsx**:

```
const SignUp = () => {

const [firstName, setfirstName] = useState('')
   const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
   const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
   const [country, setCountry] = useState('')
   const [region, setRegion] = useState('')
   const [wallet, setWallet] = useState('')

   const onChangefirstName = (e) => {
       setfirstName({ firstName: e.target.value })
   }
   const onChangeLastName = (e) => {
       setLastName({ lastName: e.target.value })
   }
   const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
       setEmail({ email: e.target.value})
   }
   const onChangeCountry = (e) => {
       setCountry({ country: e.target.value})
   }
   const onChangeRegion = (e) => {
       setRegion({ region: e.target.value })
   }
   const onChangeWallet = (e) => {
       setWallet({ wallet: e.target.value})
   }
```

Then, the **function for posting my data to MongoDB**:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   const newCustomer = {
       firstName: firstName,
       lastName: lastName,
       email: email,
       country: country,
       region: region,
       wallet: wallet
   }

   axios.post('http://localhost:5000/customer/add', newCustomer, {
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"
    },
   })
    .then(res => {
        console.log("status: ", res.status)
        setfirstName('')
        setLastName('')
        setEmail('')
        setCountry('')
        setRegion('')
        setWallet('')
    })
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
```

}

**The Sign up form itself**:

```
return (
<div className='grid-container'>
    <header>    
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>          
    </header>  
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="firstName"><b>First Name:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" 
        onChange={onChangefirstName} placeholder="Enter first Name"/>

        <label htmlFor="lastName"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" 
        onChange={onChangeLastName} placeholder="Enter last Name"/>

        <label htmlFor="Email"><b>Email:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" 
        onChange={onChangeEmail} placeholder="Enter Email"/>

        <label htmlFor="country"><b>Select Country:</b></label>
        <input type="list" name="country" 
        onChange={onChangeCountry} id="country"/>
        <datalist id="countries">
            <option value="Bub"></option>
            <option value="Dub"></option>
        </datalist>

        <label htmlFor="region"><b>Select Region</b></label>
        <input list="regions" name="region" 
        onChange={onChangeRegion} id="region"/>
        <datalist id="regions">
            <option value="Bubelbo"></option>
            <option value="Dubelbo"></option>
        </datalist>
        <label htmlFor="wallet"><b>Wallet address</b></label>
        <input type="text" 
        onChange={onChangeWallet} name="wallet"/>

        <div className="submit-container">
            <button type="submit" className="submit-btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
);
```

The backend itself works fine when I am using the Thunder Client extension in VS code. I am able to POST and GET data with no issues. For reference, here is the **server.js**, **customer.model.js** and **customer.route.js** files:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
require('dotenv').config()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true})

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('mongoDB connected successfully')
})

const customerRouter = require('./routes/customer.crypto')
app.use('/customer', customerRouter)

app.listen(5000, function() {
    console.log('express server is running on port 5000')
})
```

**customer.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    region: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    wallet: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

}, {
    timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema)
```

**customer.routes.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router()
let CustomerModel = require('../models/customer.crypto.model')

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    CustomerModel.find()
    .then(customers => res.json(customers))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err))
})

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    if(!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).send('Missing req body')
    }
    let newCustomer = new CustomerModel(req.body)

    newCustomer.save()
    .then(() => res.json('Customer added'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err))
})

module.exports = router
```

Managed to find solution, it was adding the following code in **server.js**, after **app.use(cors())**

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // to enable calls from every domain 
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // allowed actiosn
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't parsed the incoming request body before accessing **req.body**

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Also, check the response coming from node.js in **network** tab in developer tools.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

in the SignUp.jsx file on every onChange handler don't pass an object instead directly pass the value `e.target.value`

```
   const onChangefirstName = (e) => {
       setfirstName(e.target.value)
   }
   const onChangeLastName = (e) => {
       setLastName(e.target.value)
   }
   const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
       setEmail(e.target.value)
   }
   const onChangeCountry = (e) => {
       setCountry(e.target.value)
   }
   const onChangeRegion = (e) => {
       setRegion(e.target.value)
   }
   const onChangeWallet = (e) => {
       setWallet(e.target.value)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a proxy to your `package.json` :
[How to set proxy when using axios to send requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987119/how-to-set-proxy-when-using-axios-to-send-requests)

then change your axios request to `axios.post('/customer/add', newCust...`

Has worked for me before.